# get total sales qty by product from the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table sales_order which screen i provide below.

How can i get total qty from the table as the result will be as my 2nd image.

Any body please help me

```
+--------------+------------+
| Product Code | Total Sell |
+--------------+------------+
|           77 |          6 |
|           82 |          3 |
|           78 |          3 |
|           79 |          1 |
|           80 |          1 |
|           81 |          1 |
|           82 |          2 |
+--------------+------------+
```

[image: MySQL TAble]

Comment: Using Group By clause and Sum() Function

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us that you have made some effort for yourself

Comment: No pictures, thanks. I've started the ball rolling with an edit above. For further help, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table seems to contains rows saying how much (qty) of an item has been sold by product (product_code)

The following query:

```
SELECT product_code, SUM(qty) TotalSales FROM sales_order GROUP BY product_code
```

Will return one row per `product_code` (as we are `GROUP BY` that) and it will aggregate the `qty` values hence showing the total sales for it.

Comment: Thanks Juan,It works.

Comment: One more question please,how can i get the single product with highest sell .

Comment: OK, i got it from
 "SELECT product_code, SUM(qty) TotalSales FROM sales_order GROUP BY product_code order by TotalSales desc limit 1"

Thanks again,Juan

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above option, you can also make use of "GROUP BY" WITH ROLLUP to get the overall total of all the items sold.

```
SELECT product_code, SUM(qty) TotalSales FROM sales_order GROUP BY product_code WITH ROLLUP;
```

Regards